# Where does the force comes from that pushes us up when we push the ground?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

To jump we exert force on ground and because of third law of motion the ground also pushes us but from where does the force coming or what is exactly pushing us back with such a force?

Comment: [I like this answer by @BobD](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/563138/231412)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Newton's Third Law actually work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/348514/)

Comment: Please explain your difficulty in more detail.

Comment: It's a good question about biophysics, I feel like everyone missed the point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

For this to understand, you must know what type of force you are exerting on the ground. If you know that type , then from Newton's third law, you can say that the ground also applies the same type of force.

The type of force which you are exerting is normal force which is approxly due to repulsion between the charges in your feet and ground. Greater the separation lesser is the force and lesser the separation , greater is the force.

When you are standing still on the ground , the magnitude of the normal force from the ground below you is equal to your weight in magnitude and hence you are at rest.

When you try to jump , you compress the ground and thus the separation between the charges decrease and the repulsive force increases and finally you lift off.

It is similar to spring force which increases when you compress it.

Hope it helps .

Answer (score 1):

Good question, the simple idea is that as we squat down, we compress the muscle fibers like a spring, then as we quickly extend jerk upwards, all that potential energy is converted into kinetic energy by the force of our muscles contracting outwords quickly.

The ground simply gives a platform to push back against; since newton's third law states every action has an equal and opposite reaction, the ground takes the reaction of our jump and the earth gets pushed back by a small negligible amount as we jump (Interesting thought , isn't it?).

Answer (score 0):

the answer lies in the force your muscles or rather your motion generate,,, when you hit an object the force that escaped/traveled from your leg or hand will enter that object like wool and fiber or will get rebounced back at you like stone and so when you jump that same force rebounce back at you lifting your body up

basically you can try to jump by only lifting your legs dont bend dont move your hands dont make any motion and try to jump. without a force to push you away from another object you wont be able to move nor can you jump

sorry if my english is bad

Answer (score 0):

We know of four different types of forces: strong nuclear forces, electromagnetic forces, weak nuclear forces, and gravitational forces. The force from the ground on us as we push harder on the ground is increased electrical repulsion from the electrons in the atoms being pushed closer together. A theoretical physicist can probably elaborate.